# data is not getting returned in ajax success function django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to get data data from backend through ajax  in django. But i am getting error over  there.
It directly going to the error function of ajax. But in view data is getting printed.

views.py

```
def get_user_specific_android(request):
    print "you are in userspecific view"
    if request.method=="GET":
        print request.method
        craves = CraveData.objects.filter(person=request.user)
        for crave in craves:
            crave.reply= Comment.objects.filter(crave=crave)
        response = serializers.serialize("json", craves)
        print response
        return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        print "you are in else"
```

ajax call is

```
$(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                                    url: domain+"/crave/get_user_specific_android/",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType:'json',
                                    success: function(response) 
                                    {       

                                        alert("successsss");
                                        var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                        alert(parsed.post); // => alerts "bar"
                                        alert("after parse")
                                    },
                                    error: function () 
                                    {
                                    print (dataType)
                                        alert('some error');
                                    }
                                });
```

please help me out
when i print print response i am getting the data in view. Data is not getting passed to the ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

instead of uninitialized `data` variable in your javascript code.

Comment: Are its not going to success function itself,,, There is some problem in view. It directly going to error function.

Comment: @user3433253 are there any exception messages in your view function?

Comment: no,,,,,,,, response is not getting to ajax success may be a data type proble

Comment: @user3433253 do you see any js errors in your browser's development tool?

Comment: @user3433253 I suggest you to look at the response of your server in your browser then you may have more insight into this problem.